# Oneliner to create string column from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1' : [1, 2, 3, 4],\
                   'col_2' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],\
                   'col_3' : ['hey', 'ho', 'banana', 'go']})

col = df['col_1'].astype(str) + '_' + \
      df['col_2'].astype(str) + '_' + \
      df['col_3'].astype(str)

col
Out[12]: 
0       1_a_hey
1        2_b_ho
2    3_c_banana
3        4_d_go
dtype: object
```

Can anybody think of a oneliner producing `col` using the array `col_names = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']` as input?

that is  `col_sum = something_smart(col_names)`

And obviously if, for instance, `different_col_set = ['col_2', 'col_3']`

```
something_smart(different_col_set)
Out[13]: 
0         a_hey
1          b_ho
2      c_banana
3          d_go
dtype: object
```

The point is really that col_names is an array containing any subset of the column names of the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1]** Using `apply` you could `'_'.join`

```
In [5521]: df[col_names].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)
Out[5521]:
0       1_a_hey
1        2_b_ho
2    3_c_banana
3        4_d_go
dtype: object
```

and,

```
In [5523]: df[different_col_set].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)
Out[5523]:
0       a_hey
1        b_ho
2    c_banana
3        d_go
dtype: object
```

**Option 2]** Using `reduce` is faster than apply in this case.

```
In [5527]: reduce(lambda x, y: x + '_' + y, [df[c].astype(str) for c in col_names])
Out[5527]:
0       1_a_hey
1        2_b_ho
2    3_c_banana
3        4_d_go
dtype: object

In [5528]: reduce(lambda x, y: x + '_' + y, [df[c].astype(str) for c in different_col_set])
Out[5528]:
0       a_hey
1        b_ho
2    c_banana
3        d_go
dtype: object
```

Which is similar to `reduce(lambda x, y: x.astype(str) + '_' +y.astype(str), [df[x] for x in col_names])`

---

Timings

```
In [5556]: df.shape
Out[5556]: (10000, 3)

In [5553]: %timeit reduce(lambda x, y: x + '_' + y, [df[c].astype(str) for c in col_names])
10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop

In [5554]: %timeit reduce(lambda x, y: x.astype(str) + '_' +y.astype(str), [df[x] for x in col_names])
10 loops, best of 3: 22.3 ms per loop

In [5555]: %timeit df[col_names].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 254 ms per loop
```

Comment: Really quick one

Comment: Excellent :) Worked like a charm. Thank you. I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes.

Comment: `could be faster.` - I believe you add timeings ;)

Comment: Yep, indeed faster.