# Casting columns of categories to one string column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, categories

This is a follow-up to a previously asked question (asked by me :)) [Oneliner to create string column from multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514967/oneliner-to-create-string-column-from-multiple-columns)

I want to merge a subset columns in a dataframe to a new create a new string-column. @Zero was kind enough to give me the solution to this problem

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'gender' : ['m', 'f', 'f'],\
                   'code' : ['K2000', 'K2000', 'K2001']})


col_names = df.columns
df_str = df[col_names].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)
df_str
Out[17]: 
0       K2000_m
1       K2000_f
2       K2001_f
dtype: object
```

However if I introduce interval data this fails

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender' : ['m', 'f', 'f'],\
                   'code' : ['K2000', 'K2000', 'K2001'],\
                   'num' : pd.cut([3, 6, 9], [0, 5, 10])})
col_names = df.columns
df_str = df[col_names].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)
```

Ideally I would also like to transform the data to categorical data (which also fails)

```
df_cat = pd.concat([df['gender'].astype('category'), \
                    df['code'].astype('category'), \
                    df['num'].astype('category')], axis=1)
df_cat_str = df_cat[col_names].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)
```

What is going on here? And how can i acheive the desired output

```
0   K2000_m_(0, 5]
1  K2000_f_(5, 10]
2  K2001_f_(5, 10]
```

As with the previous question `col_names` should be a list containing any subset of the columns (not necessarily all columns as in this example)

Comment: `df_cat[col_names].apply('_'.join, axis=1)` will work just fine, don't need `astype(str)`

Comment: thanks... I think I perhaps posted an incomplete question. The thing is I also have interval categorical data. I will expand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need convert each column to `str` separately in lambda function:

```
df_str = df[col_names].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)
print (df_str)
0     K2000_m_(0, 5]
1    K2000_f_(5, 10]
2    K2001_f_(5, 10]
dtype: object
```